# HTML files saved to a web server

Tags: html

Do HTML files uploaded and stored on a web server become publicly available to web crawlers, such as Googlebot? I thinking that it has to be part of the sitemap file and/or be linked to from a page on the domain, but not sure.

Comment: you can submit a sitemap via Google Webmaster Tools or you can tell Google to start crawling your site when you're ready. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?hl=en_uk&pli=1 | https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

you can add a tag to your pages to tell bots not to crawl it any further. Most bots will comply. Other than that if a person can reach those pages then bots and stuff can also reach them.

Answer (score 1):

> Do HTML files uploaded and stored on a web server become publicly available to web crawlers, such as Googlebot?

Yes

> I thinking that it has to be part of the sitemap file and/or be linked to from a page on the domain, but not sure.

They have to be discoverable … somehow.

That could be a sitemap.

That could be a link (although it definitely doesn't have to be from the same domain).

It could be as simple as someone with Chrome visiting the page and Chrome reporting back (I don't know if Chrome does it, but it is certainly technically possible).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a robots.txt file to hide files from crawling bots. See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93708?hl=en for more info